# How to make proprietary database cloud compatible

Tags: cloud

My company has proprietary database. We want to give it to customers on cloud. I can see there are two ways
1) set ec2 or azure vm and install database on it
2) User should see something like create instance (like we see for oracle or MySQL) where customer can click and create his database (DBaaS?)

First way we are already supporting
I want to know about second way. Are there any steps/pdf/white paper(guide) available. We are primarily looking for azure.

Comment: I don't know about Azure, but for AWS, you could apply to become a AWS Marketplace Seller and provide your product there as a launchable instance. https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/management/tour/

Comment: Thanks. Any links/pdf/whitepaper on how to do it step by step with simplified way. I understand its not straight forward.